# Significado y origen de 'Aún/todavía tiro mis petardos'

Tags: significado-en-contexto, chile, modismos, origen

[«Me acaban de llegar de regalo dos botellas de Stolichnaya y un ramo de flores» ...De seguro son de un admirador secreto. «Todavía tiro mis petardos, como verás»](https://books.google.cl/books?id=j6cGDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT143&lpg=PT143&dq=todav%C3%ADa+tir%C3%B3+mis+petardos+google+books&source=bl&ots=kSBx5MeS2-&sig=ACfU3U0Pijq8dfjfRWzHDUtHm3rj6CvKwA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAna7PtIH0AhVuGbkGHbuhBesQ6AF6BAgSEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false%5D)

Se tiró sus petardos. A esa maletita todavía le quedan viajes.

¿Alguien conoce la relación entre 'tirar petardos' y 'seguir siendo atractiva', es acaso porque 'atrae la atención' como lo harían los 'fuegos de artificio'?

Comment: Claro, es metafórico. No creo que haya otra relación que la creada en/por la frase.

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal?

Estuve leyendo el material;

*No, no es broma. Dos botellas en un estuche rojo y muchas flores rojas. ¿Qué te parece?. De seguro que son de un admirador secreto.
Todavía tiro mis petardos, como verás*.

La última frase, efectivamente esta indicando que aún es una persona atractiva.

La relación existente entre 'tirar petardos' y 'seguir siendo atractiva es fácil. Los petardos son un tipo de fuegos artificiales utilizados como dispositivos pirotécnicos con un fin estético y de causar admiración. El sentido de tirar petardos es de atraer la atención y por tanto todavía es capaz de atraer y mantener cierto atractivo para otras personas. Así, esta comparando la capacidad que tienen los fuegos artificiales de atraer las miradas, por sus colores, por su ruido, por su belleza... en este caso, los petardos, con su persona, ya que ella entiende que aún mantiene ese atractivo de atraer hacia si a otros.

La frase tiene el mismo sentido que cuando alguien dice "*Todavía levanto pasiones*"

Cuando escribes "*A esa maletita todavía le quedan viajes*". Se refiere a que esa parte de si misma, de su persona, que consiste en "levantar pasiones ó ser atractiva", aún puede mantenerla largamente en el tiempo y seguir atrayendo en el futuro a otras personas.

Espero te haya ayudado. Saludos. Diego M.